# Menu Items Showing up Behind Remove Item dropdown Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, theme, custom

Getting this issue with our magento e-commerce site,

The remove item popup is showin below the menu,
as you can see in the picture below the menu text appears over the dropdow menu,
and are clickable if you hover over them,

[image]

Any Idea of how to fix this?

Thanks in Advance,
Gavin

Comment: You need to manage the z-index style property for both of them.

Comment: @Rizwan could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do your buttons have a background-color or are they set to transparent?

Comment: @Chris Yeah they have a background color of blue,

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Can you give the URL at all?